# How to read only first expression of my file and move to another line

Tags: java

I have a file that looks like follows:

[image]

What I need is to read only names (first column) and output it.

```
  while (sc.hasNext()) 
     System.out.println(sc.next());
```

Another solution I tried is:

```
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
     System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

The ones that are above obviously don't work. I am stuck and don't know what to do. I was trying to google my problem but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Read the line into a variable then split on space `str.split("\\s+")` and print the column you're interested in: https://repl.it/repls/TestySeashellFibonacci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    StringBuilder toPrint = new StringBuilder();
    String line = sc.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < line.length() && line.charAt(i) != ' '; i ++) {
        toPrint.append(line.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(toPrint.toString());
}
```

The reason I don't use `String.split()` is because that does lot's of unnecessary work, as it splits the entire string, and you only want the first word.

Comment: You can use `substring`  and avoid the loop?

Comment: However you don't know how big the word is.

Comment: `indexOf` to get the first space.

Comment: That will work, but I think it will be to slow because it searches the array for a space, then `subString()` itself is slow because it works by concatenating, which is a slow process.